# Can't get MS Access SQL Statement W/ Nested Joins to Function Properly

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, outer-join

Let me start by saying, I have scoured the web for help with this, tried figuring it out with a professor and used a Database Systems text book and have still not gotten this to work properly. I am attempting to finish this database as my final project for a DB management course that I'm taking, but it is also for real world use at work. My team at work currently creates access to a clinical system for end users. When we receive a request form it includes a "ServiceNow Position" (Column A) and a "ServiceNow Role" (Column B). My team has to then reference a spreadsheet, which I've attempted to attach, to find out what this correlates to in the clinical system (Column C). The row of the spreadsheet also dictates what, if any, user orgs (Column F) and user groups (column G) that the user account receives. I'm including a screenshot of the relationship between the tables prior to my modifications to the SQL statement, as once the outer joins are in place, the relationships don't illustrate.

The idea here is that I will always be given the ServiceNow role and position, it will always correlate to a row on the "Cerner_HNA_Positions" table. I will NOT necessarily always have User_Group or Organizations, though when I do have them, I may have up to 2 and 4 respectively.

[image: relationships]

My goal is to get a query that works properly, and then create a form on top of this so that who ever is working account creations can insert the ServiceNow Position and Role and have returned what the "Cerner_HNA_Positions.HNA_Position" is and any correlated User Groups and Organizations. The following is the closest SQL statement that I've gotten to function without a syntax error. However, this is returning every HNA_User_Group and HNA_Org, even though the row for HNA_Position that it returns does not have any HNA_User_Group's or Orgs assigned. I'm sure this is something to do with the fact that I've done a left join, but my goal in this was to ensure that I see the HNA_Position. Can anyone help me with this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cerner_HNA_Positions.HNA_Position,
       Cerner_HNA_Positions.Like_User, 
       Cerner_HNA_Positions.Physician, 
       Cerner_HNA_Positions.Add_Resources, 
       Cerner_HNA_User_Groups.*, 
       Cerner_HNA_Organizations.*, 
       [Service Now Position Name].Service_Now_Position, 
       [ServiceNow Role].Service_Now_Role
  FROM Cerner_HNA_User_Groups, 
       Cerner_HNA_Organizations, 
       [ServiceNow Role] 
             INNER JOIN ([Service Now Position Name] 
             INNER JOIN Cerner_HNA_Positions 
                 ON [Service Now Position Name].Service_Now_Position_ID = 
                               Cerner_HNA_Positions.Service_Now_Position_ID) 
                 ON [ServiceNow Role].Service_Now_Role_ID = 
                               Cerner_HNA_Positions.Service_Now_Role_ID
WHERE ((([Service Now Position Name].Service_Now_Position)="CIS - PowerChart") 
  AND (([ServiceNow Role].Service_Now_Role)="Resident"));
```

Spreadsheet referenced above: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vreampypo17lcd/Positions_Roles%20Sheet.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: You can post your image in another site and link it here, some one will post it directly here after that.

Comment: Just thought of that myself. I've edited to included links to DropBox in the post.

Comment: The joins to the Organizations and User_Groups tables will only work if all of the Org and UG fields in the Positions table are the same - you need separate instances of the Org and UG tables.

Comment: Thank you, citizenkong! That was the issue, I've replicated the tables the required number of times and all functions as it should. I have to ask, is this a limitation of Access that I wouldn't run into in other DB systems? It seems like this is forcing a poor design, in which I have a large amount of data redundancy. Or have I overlooked something in how I should have designed this from the start?

Either way, thanks again.